# Setting error message for an incomplete object passed through postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

Suppose I am sending a **complete** JSON object in **Postman** like the below one for **POST-end-point**:

```
{
"student": [
    {
        "studentId" : "1234",
        "feesPayment" : {
            "amount" : 500.0,
            "code" : "INR"
        }
    },
    {
        "studentId" : "5678",
        "feesPayment" : {
            "amount" : 500.0,
            "code" : "INR"
        }
    }
]
```

}

then the status code is **200 OK**

But now, I am sending the same JSON object but with some modification in the object like the below one for the same POST-end-point: (just removing the "feesPayment" object)

```
{
    "student": [
        {
            "studentId" : "1234"
        },
        {
            "studentId" : "5678"
        }
    ]
}
```

then the status code is **500 Internal Server Error** for obvious reasons and the error looks like the below one:

```
{
    "timestamp" : "2021-09-02T17:07:31",
    "status" : 500,
    "error" : "Internal Server Error",
    "message" : "Internal Server Error"
}
```

For this 500 status code, the error message is "Internal Server Error".
So my question is **How can I set this error message to something else like "Fee Payment Details are missing" instead of the default Internal Server Error message?**

Approach/Code in **Java and SpringBoot** is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

In your `Student` class, then you can write something like:

```
public class Student {
   @NotNull(message = "Error-2596-Fees Payment is required")
   private FeesPayment feesPayment;
}
```

In the RestController, you will send in `Student` payload with `@Valid` annotation

```
  public ResponseEntity<String> sendStudent(@Valid Student studentToSend) { }
```

The messages have to be constants. If you look at the code of the annotation, you will see it reads

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message
```

As the default value.  You could support internationalization and create a language properties file then define it like:

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message = "Payment is required"
```

Another thing to consider, is perhaps you wish to combine many errors and return them to the user at once.

For such a case look into `ExceptionHandler`:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> responseBody = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        List<String> allErrors = new ArrayList<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach(error -> allErrors.add(error.getDefaultMessage()));
        responseBody.put("Errors:", allErrors);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, headers, status);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it using enum like creating our own error code something like this "Error-2596-Fees Payment is required"?

Comment: updated @Arindam